# What Types should be in the Type array for Type.GetMethod when a parameter is generic?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

If I want to call a generic method through reflection, I can easily use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method) technique, unless:

1. The method can only be distinguished from another by its parameters.
2. The method has a parameter that's type is one of the method's type parameters.

How do I specify a generic parameter in the `Type[]` array when calling `Type.GetMethod(string, Type[])`?

Example:

```
public class Example
{
    //This is the one I want to call.
    public void DoSomething<T>(T t) { ... }

    public void DoSomething(Foo foo) { ... }

    public void CallDoSomething(Type type, object value)
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Example)
        .GetMethod("DoSomething", new Type[] {/* what do i put here? */ });

        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        generic.Invoke(this, value);
    }
```

Comment: It would really help if you gave us more information about what you're trying to achieve. You quite possibly want to call `GetMethods` and then find the right one from there.

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe an example will help. I'll add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you the full "thing" I use when I have to find a [`Queryable.Select<TSource, TResult> Method (IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb548743.aspx) method... It is quite complex and checks nearly all:

```
MethodInfo selectMethod = (from x in typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                           where x.Name == "Select" && x.IsGenericMethod
                           let pars = x.GetParameters()
                           where pars.Length == 2
                           let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                           where args.Length == 2 &&
                               pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(args[0]) &&
                               pars[1].ParameterType == typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(args))
                           select x).Single();
```

You can easily use it as a template.

Note that the return type isn't checked, because there is no overload for return types. The fact that the method is `static` and `public` is checked by the `GetMethods()`. I check number of parameters, number of generic arguments, type of parameters. Then I use the `Single()` to be sure that there is only one method. This should be future-proof: even if Microsoft added another `Queryable.Select` method, it would be "different".

In your specific case:

```
MethodInfo method = (from x in typeof(Example).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                     where x.Name == "DoSomething" && x.IsGenericMethod
                     let pars = x.GetParameters()
                     where pars.Length == 1
                     let args = x.GetGenericArguments()
                     where args.Length == 1 &&
                         pars[0].ParameterType == args[0]
                     select x).Single();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Example)
    .GetMethods().First(mi => mi.Name == "DoSomething" && mi.IsGenericMethod);
```

Depending on how many method overloads you have, you might have to make the predicate more specific.